# Centering content in tables with borders

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have encountered a problem using `\centering` within the tabular environment.  The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|} \hline
\centering{Lolcats}  & \centering{.com} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

generates the error "`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`"  The error leaves by removing "`\\ \hline`", but this also removes the last line of the table.  Any ideas on what has gone wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: What is `\centering` supposed to do? The column already has center alignment.

Comment: Sorry, I have now replaced `c|c` with `r|r`.  I have greatly simplified my original table, in which the `\centering` command does have an effect.

Comment: You replaced the same type of command with another, as `r,l,c` all make a box that is just wide enough for the cell to fit in.

Comment: If you want to override the alignment for a single cell, use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Lolcats}` (add also the rules, if you really want ruled tables). Please, make a more significant example.

Comment: The original table is such that additional rows make the entries of the table wider than necessary.  I am seeking to have some rows right justified, while a select few centered.  More exactly, though, I am wondering simply what is causing the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you also want to center the cells vertically. LaTeX `tabular`s have a different spacing model as HTML. Invisible struts help to keep a uniform line spacing. Via struts, the `\baselineskip` space is divided in 70% above and 30% below the base line. Since your text does not contain glyphs with descenders, the space below the base line looks too large in comparison to the space above the text.

The following example shows some workarounds. For simplicity the vertical margins will use the same as the horizontal: `\tabcolsep`.

By redefining

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
```

the effect of the struts are nullified. The margin below can be added via the optional argument of `\\`. The margin above can be created by increasing the height of the row. `\raisebox{\tabcolsep}{\vphantom{L}}` applied to the highest letter `L` creates this invisible artificial height.

The next example uses an additional row instead with the height of the margin.

The example file concludes with an example, how this can be done with `\fbox`.
`\kern\fboxrule` prevents the double line width of the touching `\fbox`es.

Package `array` moves the vertical lines outside the cells. The effect is visible in comparison with the `\fbox` example. With package `array` the widths are the same. Otherwise, the `tabular` examples have smaller widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
  Lolcats & .com \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    \raisebox{\tabcolsep}{\vphantom{L}}%
    Lolcats  & .com \\[\tabcolsep]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\endgroup

\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    \rule{0pt}{\tabcolsep} & \\
    Lolcats  & .com \\[\tabcolsep]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\endgroup

\setlength{\fboxsep}{\tabcolsep}
\fbox{Lolcats}\kern-\fboxrule\fbox{\vphantom{L}.com}

\end{document}
```

> [image]